# Unable to get UIImageView from UITabBar swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am following [tutorial](https://github.com/pwax/AnimatedTabBarItemImage/blob/master/AnimatedTabBarItemImage/AnimatedTabBarController.swift) to animate tab bar images. The given line of code doesn't work for me

```
secondItemView.subviews.first as! UIImageView
```

as it gets data of type UITabBarButtonLabel and not UIImageView.
I added tag value 1 so that I can get UIImageView using tag value
[image]

```
secondItemView.viewWithTag(1)
```

returns nil. What is the other way to get UIImageView's reference?

Code

```
@objc public class MTMainScreenTabsController : UITabBarController {
var secondItemImageView: UIImageView!
public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let secondItemView = self.tabBar.subviews[0]


    print(secondItemView.subviews)
    print(secondItemView.viewWithTag(1))

    //self.secondItemImageView = secondItemView.subviews.secon
    var item: UITabBarItem! = self.tabBar.items![0]


    //self.secondItemImageView = secondItemView.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
}

public override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

public override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item.tag == 1 {
        self.secondItemImageView.transform = .identity
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            () -> Void in
                //let rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            let rotation = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2))
                self.secondItemImageView.transform = rotation
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: give tab bar tag 1 and check  it

Comment: Can you update your question with more code?

Comment: @LuanTran Added code

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya You mean on TabBar in "View" should i make the "Tag" 1?

Comment: In which Xcode, you use it?Because "UITabBarButtonLabel" class is not in UIKit

Comment: ya and you should access your tab bar item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good practice to strictly depend on the order of subviews as it may change in the future. If you are sure that `secondItemView.subviews` contain an instance of `UIImageView` you can find it like this:

```
let imageView = secondItemView.subviews.flatMap { $0 as? UIImageView }.first
```

An `imageView` variable would be an optional containing either `nil` or an actual `UIImageView` if there was any subview of this type. Flat map would iterate through subviews and try to cast each to `UIImageView` - if it fails the result will be filtered out, if not it will then be put in the result array from which you're taking first element.

Answer (score -2):

Use My code this one is help you

```
class AnimatedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var secondItemImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let secondItemView = self.tabBar.subviews[1]
        self.secondItemImageView = secondItemView.subviews.first as! UIImageView
        self.secondItemImageView.contentMode = .center

    }

    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

        if item.tag == 1{
            //do our animations

            self.secondItemImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(), animations: { () -> Void in

                let rotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
                self.secondItemImageView.transform = rotation

                }, completion: nil)
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: copied from medium